# Existe-t-il un site où l'on peut recevoir critiques et corrections pour ses écrits ?

Tags: ressources

Connaissez-vous un site où l'on pourrait publier ses écrits et puis avoir des critiques et des corrigés par la communauté ?

Answer (score 3):

Je pense que tu pourrais trouver [Lang-8.com](http://lang-8.com/) intéressant.

On écrit une "entry" chaque jour, par exemple, que les autres corrigeront. Tu peux choisir 2 langues (sans paiement), ou plus de langues mais avec paiement.

Answer (score 1):

Il existe des communautés d'écrivains et auteurs amateurs un peu partout sur le net, il suffit de chercher et d'essayer. Tout ce qui est plus professionnel sera payant.

Modestement, je peux proposer [une adresse](http://www.atorgael.com) qui n'est rien d'autre que mon site où nous nous amusons à écrire dans les domaines de la fantasy, de la SF, et du fantastique.
Nous nous efforçons de commenter, corriger les textes qui nous sont proposés dans la mesure de nos capacités. Les discussions se passent sur [les forums](http://forums.atorgael.com).